# Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_main' while adding native Binding Dll and Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Database

Tags: ios, firebase, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.ios

I have tried adding and implementing the native Binding Dll and Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Database in my Xamarin project using NuGet but I am unable to build my project due to below error :

Error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /**/**/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone8.1-11.4/mtouch-cache/arm64/main.o (Location related to previous error) (MT5213)

Duplicate symbol in: /**/**/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone8.1-11.4/mtouch-cache/leveldb-library(leveldb_main.o) (Location related to previous error) (MT5213)

Also, I have added "--registrar:static" in the additional mtouch arguments.

Kindly suggest with the best possible way to resolve the above issues.

Thank you.

Comment: Just in case, have you tried deleting bin/obj and also double checked the --registrar:static is correctly set in mtoucharguments for the configuration you're trying to build?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that too. But still no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have added **"--registrar:static"** argument properly try to follow below steps
In Visual Studio,

- Open the project settings of your iOS project
- Go to Build > iOS Build
- Select Configuration Release and Platform iPhone * Next to Supported architectures 
  *select ARMv7 + ARM64 instead of ARMv7 + ARMv7s + ARM64*.

& make sure Update to macOS High Sierra

> The most recent version of Xcode requires macOS High Sierra (10.13). developers should update to macOS High Sierra as soon as possible in order to support the Xcode 9.3 SDKs and API.
>   Find another possible answer [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/251326/error-mt5212-native-linking-failed-duplicate-symbo.html)

Moreover, [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/251326/error-mt5212-native-linking-failed-duplicate-symbo.html) thread might be helpful

Comment: I have checked for all the above scenario and I am using Xcode Version 9.4.1 and macOS High Sierra (10.13). Still, the issues remain the same.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestion. "--registrar:static" did work for me, I did a silly mistake by adding the dll as the references to my project, Instead all I had to do was to create a NuGet Package and add the binding dll through it.