# Native linking failed, duplicate symbol:"_cxa+throw" when enabling the AppCenter crash and analytics in Xamarin Forms iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-app-center

I'm facing the below errors when enabling the AppCenter crash and analytics in the App.xaml.cs file like below,

```
protected override void OnStart()
{
   AppCenter.Start("android={my secret code};" + "ios={my secret code}", typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));
}
```

If comment on this code, I didn't get any errors.

> Native linking failed. Please review the build log.
>   linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>   Duplicate symbol in: /Users/macbook-02/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MyProject.iOS/fa397694646d06672e8f8c7f7683e7fe/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/AppCenterCrashes.a(MSCrashesCXXExceptionHandler.o) (Location related to previous error)
>   Duplicate symbol in: /Users/macbook-02/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MyProject.iOS/fa397694646d06672e8f8c7f7683e7fe/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/libHockeySDK.a(BITCrashCXXExceptionHandler.o) (Location related to previous error)
>   1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
>   Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: ''___cxa_throw''.
>   Native linking failed. Please review the build log.

I try to fix it by the answer given in the below links but that's not resolving my issue,

[Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_main' while adding native Binding Dll and Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51178283/native-linking-failed-duplicate-symbol-main-while-adding-native-binding-dll)

https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/issues/111

Comment: Can you please try moving `/Users/macbook-02/Library/Caches/Xamarin/` to other place to see if this error persists?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have a check with [whether adding the App Center SDK to your solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/Xamarin#3-add-the-app-center-sdk-to-your-solution) .If you have followed up that , remember to add reference in project:

```
using Microsoft.AppCenter;
using Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics;
using Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes;
```

Then clean your project and rebuild it .

Comment: Junior Jiang - MSFT - Thanks for the reply. I implement the AppCenter crash and analytics by referring to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/Xamarin#3-add-the-app-center-sdk-to-your-solution document only. And also i added the reference in my project. But still I'm facing this issue.

Comment: @GanesanVG Okey, have you checked if the current version of Xamarin Forms is the latest version.

Comment: I have checked with the latest versions for both Xamarin.Forms and AppCenter related packages. But still, the issue occurs.

Comment: @GanesanVG Could you share a sample link with App Center function ? I will check it in my local site .

Comment: Junior Jiang - MSFT - Its big application, not a simple sample. Sorry, I couldn't able to share our application.

Comment: @GanesanVG Got it , I will continue to search it, if good solution will update here :)

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the native linker encounters duplicate symbols between all the native libraries. You can see detailed information on this error here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/mtouch-errors#mt5212-native-linking-failed-duplicate-symbol- .

Comment: Your right. I have checked these too. But that also, couldn't resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Link type in your iOS project properties:
Right click iOS project > Properties
in iOS Build tab change Linker Behavior to **Link Framework SDKs Only**

[image]